# how to create matrix class in C# or java

Tags: java, c#, matrix, xna

I'm taking graphic course and on the first class the instructor told us to write our own matrix class (4 * 4 matrices) & homogeneous point. She told us to use either Java or Visual studio C# and I'm really good at both of them *I don't know which language is better for graphic java or c#* . it just she didn't give us any books or reference and I'm not expert in graphic I looked at  XNA matrix but I couldn't understand how to start *I just don't know where to start?*

Comment: `I'm really good at both` use anyone then!

Comment: I don't know how to start ? like what methods,constructor ,variables ..etc ?

Comment: @withoutname then you are not good

Answer (score 2):

Start with a class:

```
public class Matrix {    
}
```

## Fields

Inside your matrix classes, there are a few approaches:

A backing field 2 dimensional array:

```
private float[][] values;
```

A single array to store the whole matrix, with dimensions separately:

```
private int m;
private int n;
private float[] values;
```

Fixed variables could be used for smaller matrices when the size of the matrix cannot vary.

```
private float m1n1;
private float m1n2;
private float m2n1;
private float m2n2;
```

## Constructors

As a minimum, a variable size matrix class needs to know its size, then it could initialise to the identity matrix for square matrices.

```
public Matrix(int rows, int columns){
  //initialise fields you chose to use from above
}
```

Static constructors for creating initialized matrices:

```
public static Matrix newIdentity(int size){
}

public static Matrix new4x4Translate(float x, float y, float z){
}

public static Matrix new4x4Rotate(...){
}
```

## Methods

You'll need methods to do the normal matrix mathematical commands, e.g.:

```
public Matrix multiply(Matrix other){
}

public Point multiply(Point point){
}
```

Where `Point` is 1 dimensional vector. You'll need to check that the dimensions match.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your first class I'm pretty sure she didn't intend for you to start creating graphics.

Matrices are used a lot in graphic algorithms so I'm pretty sure what she wants you to do is a class that can handle common matrices interaction like multiplication and such.

At the least be able to multiply a point and a matrix.
One class for the matrix, one for your point. Variables for each coordinate; (X,Y,Z) and (X1, Y1, X2, Y2) for your matrix.
Have a separate class use both of them for calculation.

Start by writing a test for a known answer and write code that solves that.

Check out this page: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You good in both then choose any one because both language(java,C#) working is same but only writing syntax is different so,its depends on you which one is better for you.